# How to calculate $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Is there a general  method for calculating things like
$\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}[x,y]/I$ ?

Maximal ideals are
$ \{(x-\tilde{a},y-\tilde{b}): b^2-a^3=0\}$
because of
$f(x,y)(x-a)+g(x,y)(x-b)=y^2-x^3$ evaluated in $x=a$ and $y=b$.
 But how to calculate non-maximal ideals?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Do you know how to compute $\text{Spec } \mathbb{C}[x, y]$? (This is the only number of variables above $1$ for which there's a reasonable answer.)

Answer (score 2):

Just a hint. $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}[x,y]/I$ is in bijection with the set of all primes $p$ in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that $I(=(y^{2}-x^{3}))\subseteq p$. Now, can you describe what are the elements of $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}[x,y]$? (Hint: you have the zero ideal and the maximal ideals in that spectrum and certainly all the principal ideals generated by an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. Prove that these exhaust all the possibilities).

Comment: I think there is a little typo. It should be: $p$ in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that $I(=(y^{2}-x^{4}))\subseteq p$. In other words, there is bijection between $Var(I)$ and $Spec(R/I)$.

Comment: @bjn Sure, thanks!